# SetBitmap fails when loading bitmap via LoadBitmapA, but not via LoadImage

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a strange problem.

When I run the following code, stat is true, stat2 is null, and the icon is not displayed. When I comment the one before last line, and uncomment the last, the icon is correctly displayed.

```
CBitmap GreenButton;
BOOL stat = GreenButton.LoadBitmapA(IDB_GREENBUTTON);
HBITMAP hb = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), "<path to same bitmap in the project>", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

m_Recording.ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, 0);
HBITMAP stat2 = m_Recording.SetBitmap(HBITMAP(GreenButton));
//  m_Recording.SetBitmap(hb);
```

What could cause this failure?

Comment: `LoadBitmap` is as old as the hills. It's been superseded by `LoadImage`and again by the GDI+ class `Bitmap`. In fact MS's own docs state: `"LoadBitmap is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use LoadImage and DrawFrameControl."` What would cause this failure? Old code not compatible with the range of images available today. The GDI+ classes allow the loading of 32bit png/bmps etc. Pngs are much nicer to use than BMPs - why not make the switch?

Comment: You're suspiciously doing `SetBitmap` with an argument supposed to be soon destroyed by `~CBitmap`.

Comment: Using

    HBITMAP hb = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_GREENBUTTON), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_SHARED);

did the trick.

Thank!

Comment: Your calls do different things. One is loading a bitmap from a file, the other from a resource. If loading from a file works, but loading from a resource doesn't, then you probably screwed up your resources. What's odd, still, is that you are providing a module handle when loading from a file. That surely doesn't make sense.